# How to add a maven archetype from mvncentral to local archetype-repo.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have created an archetype and added it to maven central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/nl/ivonet/javaee8-essentials-archetype/)

Now to test if I can get it from the central repo I removed my local versions from `~/.m2/repository` and also removed the references form `~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml`

I tried `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=nl.ivonet:javaee8-essentials-archetype -U` to generate a new project but I don't get my archetype in the filtered list.

How do I get the apache central hosted archetype in my local catalog? without having to build it myself that is

The goal is to get it offline available again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1

You can get the dependencies with the maven dependency plugin as follows

```
mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=nl.ivonet \
   -DartifactId=javaee8-essentials-archetype -Dversion=0.0.2
```

And then next time when you are offline or you want to work with your cache, you call the generate with `-o` flag (offline)

```
mvn archetype:generate (...) -o
```

Option 2

Use `mvn archetype:crawl` which searches your local repository for available archetypes and creates a catalog file under `~/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml`.

Then you can use the catalog file when generating archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=file://path/to/catalog (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=javaee8-essentials-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=0.0.2 -U` You haven't provided the version, that's why your command didn't worked.